# 2d cube in canvas algorithm

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there a way to create a cube in 2d? as in what a 3d cube would look like from any angle? Basically something like [this](http://virtualmathmuseum.org/Polyhedra/Cube/Cube.png), basically three quadrilaterals that combined look like a cube.

I would like to generate random cubes, so whatever formula would need to allow for variations

Comment: just draw the squares and then use transformations to create the cube... be wary: this involves some math

Comment: I have done something like that before, just need some [computer graphic knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I think I'll need, I just need help with the formula

Answer (score 1):

You can learn the transformation algorithms in this neat little 2d-->3d library called pre3D.

It probably offers more features than you need, but it’s only 36k, and you could always cut out the features you don’t need for an even smaller download size.

You can see the demo here (including an animating 2d-->3d box):  http://deanm.github.com/pre3d/monster.html

You can get the code here: https://github.com/deanm/pre3d